# ROLL IN / OUT in SAP Memory Management

Tags: sap-basis

I have a question concerning the ROLL IN/ROLL OUT operations. According to (chapter "Functions of the SAP Memory Management System" in the SAP Help documentation "SAP Memory Management (BC-CST-MM)"):

> *"Whenever a dialog step is executed, a roll action occurs between the roll buffer in the shared memory and the memory area, which is allocated according to ztta/roll_first in a dialog process. Then the area in the shared memory is accessed that belongs to this user context.*
>
> *The following graphic displays the roll process performed by the dispatcher.*
>
> - *Roll-in: cross-user data is rolled in from the common resource in the work process (and is processed there).*
> - *Roll-out: User-specific data is rolled out from the work process in the common resource (after the dialog step has ended).*
>
> *The common resource stands for the different SAP memory types."*

According to this passage in SAP Help documentation is the Roll IN = From Shared To Local and The Roll Out = From Local To Shared. Am I getting it right?

Because this figure made me a little bit confused :

[image]

is the figure false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the figure, the terms "Roll in" and "Roll out" need to be exchanged.